# Trying a Recursion problem (my first time)

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to solve a Digital Root problem using Recursion. It seems to work for the first time around but not for the consecutive times.
Here's what I want it to do:

```
digital_root(16)
=> 1 + 6
=> 7

digital_root(942)
=> 9 + 4 + 2
=> 15 ...
=> 1 + 5
=> 6

digital_root(132189)
=> 1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9
=> 24 ...
=> 2 + 4
=> 6

digital_root(493193)
=> 4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3
=> 29 ...
=> 2 + 9
=> 11 ...
=> 1 + 1
=> 2
```

Here's what I got:

```
def digital_root(n)
  arr = n.to_s.split("")
  arr.size > 1 ? arr[0].to_i + digital_root(arr[1..-1].join).to_i : arr.join.to_i
end
```

Let me know how to make it work regardless of how many layers I need.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the function processes only 1 digits in 1 call. (`4` for `digital_root(493193)`)

Let's process 1 layer in 1 call and call next one (`digital_root(29)`).

```
def digital_root(n)
  arr = n.to_s.split("")
  arr.size > 1 ? digital_root(arr.map(&:to_i).sum) : arr.join.to_i
end
```

And slightly better version.

```
def digital_root(n)
  n < 10 ? n : digital_root(n.digits.sum)
end
```

Comment: I think you can use `chars` instead of `split`. And maybe `sum(&:to_i)` might work.

Comment: Or just `n.digits.sum`. No need for string conversion.

Comment: `digits` reverses the order of characters, so printing steps (as the OP requires) may then need adjustment.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! This shows me new features I didn't know much about. Gonna study them

Comment: As you say, #2 is preferable to #1, so I suggest you remove #1 from your answer. The fact that you came up with #1 and @zippie suggested the use of `Integer#digits` in #2 (who received your thanks and recognition in a comment) is irrelevant. Our goal is to provide the best answer, period. Sometimes two approaches are equally good, so presenting both has value. That's not the case here. I suggest you also give the link [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) as some readers may not be familiar with that method.